# Leaflet - add custom icon to markers layer to use with L.Control.Search

Tags: javascript, search, leaflet, icons, marker

I've been tryin to find solution to make it work or the answer on this question, but i failed, so here it is:

I have a custom-made imaginary map (let's say it's from the game) and i wanted to add search bar to search though markers that i've added. previous method didn't allow me to add 'L.Control.Search' to search though markers, so I adopted a method from https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search using example which is called 'outside.html'.

I use a function to add markers to the LayerGroup from the array. so I split it in two arrays to add to two different groups.

previously i was using this method to add custom icon:

```
// Add Marker
    var city1 = L.marker(map.unproject([5074, 4952], map.getMaxZoom()), {icon: city1_icon})
        .bindPopup('<b>City1</b>').bindTooltip('C1', {permanent: true}).openTooltip();

// Custom Icon
var city1_icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'ICONS/RENDERS/city1.png',
    iconSize: [45, 100],
    iconAnchor: [22.5, 100],
    popupAnchor: [0, -75],
    shadowUrl: 'ICONS/RENDERS/city1_shadow.png',
    shadowSize: [41, 35],
    shadowAnchor: [0, 35]
});
```

but now to add markers, i'm using this method and marker's icon don't change from default:

```
//sample data values to populate map
// ==================================================================================
    var data = [
        {"loc":[5627, 3946], "title":"City11", "coord":"123"},
    ];
    
    var data2 = [
        {"loc2":[3326, 5544], "title2":"City21", "coord2":"321"},
    ];

var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup();  //layer contain searched elements
map.addLayer(markersLayer);

var markersLayer2 = new L.LayerGroup();
map.addLayer(markersLayer2);

map.addControl( new L.Control.Search({
    layer: L.layerGroup([markersLayer, markersLayer2]),
    initial: false,
    zoom: 4,
    collapsed: false,
}) ); // end addControl
//inizialize search control

////////////populate map with markers from sample data
for(i in data) {
    var title = data[i].title,  //value searched
        loc = data[i].loc,      //position found
        coord = data[i].coord,  //icon used
        cityMarker = new L.Marker(map.unproject(loc, map.getMaxZoom()), {title: title}, {icon: city1_icon})
        .bindPopup('title: '+ title + ' ' + coord);
    markersLayer.addLayer(cityMarker);
}

for(i in data2) {
    var title2 = data2[i].title2,   //value searched
        loc2 = data2[i].loc2,       //position found
        coord2 = data2[i].coord2,   //icon used
        cityMarker2 = new L.Marker(map.unproject(loc2, map.getMaxZoom()), {title: title2}, {icon: city2_icon})
        .bindPopup('title: '+ title2 + ' ' + coord2);
    markersLayer2.addLayer(cityMarker2);
}

// Custom Icons
    var city1_icon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'ICONS/RENDERS/city1.png',
        iconSize: [45, 100],
        iconAnchor: [22.5, 100],
        popupAnchor: [0, -75],
        shadowUrl: 'ICONS/RENDERS/city1_shadow.png',
        shadowSize: [41, 35],
        shadowAnchor: [0, 35]
    });

    // Custom Icon
    var city2_icon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'ICONS/RENDERS/city2.png',
        iconSize: [45, 100],
        iconAnchor: [22.5, 100],
        popupAnchor: [0, -75],
        shadowUrl: 'ICONS/RENDERS/city2_shadow.png',
        shadowSize: [41, 35],
        shadowAnchor: [0, 35]
    });
```

everything except custom icons works.

P.S. i'm not very good with JS

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The `L.Marker` constructor method takes a dictionary of options as its second argument; you're passing it two dicrtionaries as second and third arguments. So instead of `{title: title2}, {icon: city2_icon}` it should be `{title: title2, icon: city2_icon}`.

Comment: Thank you for your idea! i have tried it earlier, and tried it now. for some mysterious reason it breaks the adding sequence of new markers. (i know that because only the first item from the first layer appears in search with no icon of a marker displayed on map). it seems like adding anything except `title` into marker's options breaks the function :(

UPD: so i found the issue, i was putting var for icons below the initial code, and when i transferred it above the initial function it suddenly started to display custom icons. thank you for your help, @IvanSanchez

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was pretty simple, thankfully to @IvanSanchez.

First off you need to put your variables for new custom icons above the new markers function. If you put it below the function it will not execute the custom icon variable at all.

```
var newCustomIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'ICONS/newCustomIcon.png',
    iconSize: [45, 100],
    iconAnchor: [22.5, 100],
    popupAnchor: [0, -75],
    shadowUrl: 'ICONS/newCustomIcon_shadow.png',
    shadowSize: [41, 35],
    shadowAnchor: [0, 35]
});
```

Second off you'll need to add to the same options part of L.Marker these changes like:

instead of `{title: title2}, {icon: newCustomIcon}` it should be `{title: title2, icon: newCustomIcon}`

```
for(i in data) {
    var title = data[i].title,  //value searched
        loc = data[i].loc,      //position found
        cityMarker = new L.Marker(map.unproject(loc, map.getMaxZoom()), {title: title, icon: newCustomIcon})
        .bindPopup('title: '+ title + ' ' + coord);
    markersLayer.addLayer(cityMarker);
}
```

thanks :)